# How to fix long text overflowing in the margin (latex)?

Tags: latex, paragraph

I have a paragraph with long text like below

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T5]{fontenc}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "\text" macro
\usepackage[fontsize=14pt]{scrextend}%font mặc định
\usepackage[paperheight=29.7cm,paperwidth=21cm,right=2cm,left=3cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}%font a4
\usepackage{mathptmx}%ngôn ngữ time new roman
\begin{document}

Hiện nay, Bộ Y tế đã cấp phép 03 loại thuốc kháng virus chứa hoạt chất Molnupiravir sản xuất trong nước, gồm:

- Molravir 400: hàm lượng Molnupiravir 400 mg, dạng viên nang cứng, tuổi thọ 6 tháng, do Công ty Cổ phần dược phẩm Boston Việt Nam sản xuất (Giá bán buôn dự kiến: 11.550 VNĐ/viên).

- Movinavir: hàm lượng 200 mg Molnupiravir, dạng viên nang cứng, tuổi thọ 6 tháng, do Công ty cổ phần hóa dược phẩm Mekophar sản xuất (Giá bán lẻ dự kiến: 9.455 VNĐ/viên)

- Molnuporavir Stella 400: hàm lượng 400 mg Molnupiravir, dạng viện nang cứng, tuổi thọ 8 tháng, do Công ty TNHH Liên doanh Stellapharm – chi nhánh 1 sản xuất (Giá bán lẻ dự kiến: 13.750 VNĐ/viên)

\textit{(Thông tin về các thuốc kháng virus do Bộ Y tế cấp phép lưu hành và giá kê khai của thuốc được đăng tải trên trang https://dichvucong.dav.gov.vn/congbogiathuoc/index, các cơ sở kinh doanh dược tra cứu để cập nhật)}.
\end{document}
```

The line that has the long text "https://dichvucong.dav.gov.vn/congbogiathuoc/index" is overflowing, how can I align it so that the text does not overflow like in Word. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't set urls in plain text. They often contain problematic letters and can cause problems in your document. You can instead use packages like `url` or `hyperref` to set them.

I would also suggest to use an `itemize` environment for your itemisation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T5]{fontenc}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "\text" macro
\usepackage[fontsize=14pt]{scrextend}%font mặc định
\usepackage[paperheight=29.7cm,paperwidth=21cm,right=2cm,left=3cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}%font a4
\usepackage{mathptmx}%ngôn ngữ time new roman
\usepackage{url}
\begin{document}

Hiện nay, Bộ Y tế đã cấp phép 03 loại thuốc kháng virus chứa hoạt chất Molnupiravir sản xuất trong nước, gồm:

\begin{itemize}
\item Molravir 400: hàm lượng Molnupiravir 400 mg, dạng viên nang cứng, tuổi thọ 6 tháng, do Công ty Cổ phần dược phẩm Boston Việt Nam sản xuất (Giá bán buôn dự kiến: 11.550 VNĐ/viên).

\item Movinavir: hàm lượng 200 mg Molnupiravir, dạng viên nang cứng, tuổi thọ 6 tháng, do Công ty cổ phần hóa dược phẩm Mekophar sản xuất (Giá bán lẻ dự kiến: 9.455 VNĐ/viên)

\item Molnuporavir Stella 400: hàm lượng 400 mg Molnupiravir, dạng viện nang cứng, tuổi thọ 8 tháng, do Công ty TNHH Liên doanh Stellapharm – chi nhánh 1 sản xuất (Giá bán lẻ dự kiến: 13.750 VNĐ/viên)
\end{itemize}

\textit{(Thông tin về các thuốc kháng virus do Bộ Y tế cấp phép lưu hành và giá kê khai của thuốc được đăng tải trên trang \url{https://dichvucong.dav.gov.vn/congbogiathuoc/index}, các cơ sở kinh doanh dược tra cứu để cập nhật)}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: but the font after \url text is ugly, how can i change it

Comment: @tungsondkh You can change it with `\urlstyle{rm}`, although typewriter font is pretty much the standard for urls

Comment: but what if the long text is not a link? How can i justify text like in word

Comment: non-url text should be justified automatically, see the first line of the example.